# g_csrf_token is missing when running app on GCP Cloud Run

Tags: cookies, google-signin, google-cloud-run, vercel, csrf-token

I have an application with a frontend hosted on Vercel and the backend hosted on GCP Cloud Run. My app implements Google Identity to enable Sign in with Google and One Tap. The frontend and the backend **don't** have the same domain.

When I run my app locally in a container and sign in, my server correctly receives the webhook  call from Google with credentials, and `g_csrf_token` both present in the body and the cookie.

However, when I run my app on GCP Cloud Run the  `g_csrf_token` cookie is missing so my server won't handle the webhook call and responds with `403`. That is because it can't verify the equality between the CSRF token in the body and the one in the cookie.

So my question is, what could cause this behavior ? I need to be able to receive the cookie set by Google.

I already try to set the `data-state_cookie_domain` attribute of the `g_id_onload` element.

Comment: CSRF - Cross-Site Request Forgery. You are using two different domains. That is Cross Site. The purpose of CSRF is to prevent using different domains.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley, this sounds pretty obvious, I feel little bit dumb. Thank you a lot for commenting. I now have a different question, how can I verify a csrf token if my frontend and my backend are on a different subdomain of a same domain ?

Comment: You need to know what the correct value is to check it. If one service creates the token, the other service must also know the value to validate it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But the value is generated by Google and I don't know how to reproduce it. I use the HTML code of Google Identity Services. https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#element_with_id_g_id_onload

Comment: You have answered yourself. If you don't know the value of the token then you cannot validate it. That is the purpose of CSRF. To prevent using different domains. Therefore don't use different domains.